# Get element in newly opened window with GreaseMonkey. window.open and href not available

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have a GreaseMonkey script that clicks a button, which opens a new window. I then want to get an element from that new window. However, I am not able to get a reference for that new window. The focused window remains on the old window instead of transferring to the new window.

The issue is that the button runs its own javascript function to open the new window. So I can't reference the new window with window.open. The button also does not have a href for me to get its link.

Is there a way for me to reference child windows (like the opposite of window.opener)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my own problem in a roundabout way.

I used an event listener for the load event. With this, I am able to get a handle on the new window. The event listener checks that the current page is the one I'm expecting, then gets the desired element and then does the action.

Using the load event listener allows me to reference child windows, but in a roundabout way.